# Mozilla extension is unexpectedly logging user out after a short time

Tags: javascript, php, browser, google-chrome-extension, mozilla

I implemented a login feature in my Mozilla extension, when user are login then some important script should start running. but when user login after like 2/3 hours the script stops running to make the script continue running the user need to re-login again

And i implemented an icon colour change that informs user when the extension is login and logout. But when this issue happens the icon colour will still remain in the colour designated for already login

And also there are times when i will need to login twice before the script start running

The login is base on if obj is yes or no
So if it yes scripts should start running but if no script won't work

Please how do i solve this issue that makes script stop working all of a sudden and the issue that makes users to sometimes login twice before script can function properly

```js
document.querySelector("#go").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'http://xc-addon.herokuapp.com/login';
  var params = 'username=' + document.getElementById("uname").value + '&password=' + document.getElementById("psw").value + '';
  http.open('POST', url, true);
  //Send the proper header information along with the request
  http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.querySelector("#go").value = "one moment please..";
    document.querySelector("#go").disabled = true;
    //Call a function when the state changes.
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      if (http.responseText == '{"message":"true","body":"login successful"}') {
        var obj;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            browser.storage.local.set({
              obj: obj
            }, function() {
              browser.storage.local.set({
                show: {
                  name: "ticket",
                  eats: "no"
                }
              }, function() {
                browser.storage.local.set({
                  autoReplaceOnLoad: true
                });
                browser.storage.local.set({
                  autoReplacePeriodically: false
                });
                browser.storage.local.set({
                  enableSubscription: true
                });
                browser.storage.local.set({
                  subscriptionUrl: "http://xc-addon.herokuapp.com/data_actuals/" + document.querySelector("#uname").value
                });
                localStorage.setItem("logged", true);
                browser.browserAction.setIcon({
                  path: "../icons/x32.png"
                }, function() {
                  document.querySelector("#go").textContent = "welcome " + document.querySelector("#uname").value + "!";
                });
              });
            });
            alert("wait for the welcome message!");
          }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://xc-addon.herokuapp.com/data/" + document.querySelector("#uname").value, true);
        xhttp.send();
      } else {
        browser.browserAction.setIcon({
          path: "../icons/redX32.png"
        });
        window.close();
      }
    }
  }
  http.send(params);
});
```

Comment: just some points.
- why won't check the json instead of string
here : if (http.responseText == '{"message":"true","body":"login successful"}')
- not clear how you are handling the login in your server side

Comment: I don't really know if this is the best way to implement the login feature maybe there are other ways. And the server only return success or failure response.

Comment: yes, there many ways to handle login but it should be at the server side.
The second ajax request after login looks unnecessary since you can do that in server side

Comment: Do you have a better solution, please you can share and i don't mind you helping out writing the code as well